# Sorting references with given bibliographystyle

Tags: natbib, sorting

I am writing a scientific article and plan to submit it to a Springer journal. Unfortunately, Springer's LaTeX support is not very satisfying. You are forced to use Springer's LaTeX class *svjour3* as well as one of their bibliography styles (both can be downloaded [here](http://www.springeropen.com/authors/tex)).

Currently I am struggeling with the sorting in the bibliography as I want to sort by appearance, hence the first citation in the article should be cited with [1]. This works well with the bibliographystyle *unsrtnat*, but doesn't work with *spmpsci*, which I must use for the journal. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
This citation~\cite{Smith2009} should be named \emph{1}, while this one here~\cite{Fisher2013} should be numbered \emph{2}. How can we resort by appearance?

\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

With the bibliography file references.bib:

```
@article{Fisher2013,
author = {Michael Fisher},
journal = {Fisher journal},
pages = {1--10},
title = {The one title},
volume = {12},
number = {12},
year = {2013}
}

@article{Smith2009,
author = {John Smith},
journal = {Smith journal},
pages = {11--20},
title = {The other title},
volume = {13},
number = {1},
year = {2009}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose one could edit a copy of the file `spmpsci.bst` to disable the alphabetical sorting of the entries. However, given that you're evidently preparing your paper for a submission to a *Springer* journal that requires you to use `spmpsci.bst`, I think it would be a really bad idea to edit (a copy of) that file -- unless, of course, you've been given explicit permission and encouragement to modify the style file.

Answer (score 4):

I was asking Springer's support and they answered that I shall ignore the problem and they will manage to sort the references correctly upon acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file:

> spmpsci.bst

Search for SORT (Case sensitive search)

There should be one instance with "SORT" (all caps). Currently, it's in line 1463. **Delete this line or comment it out**. Clear cache. Recompile. Voila...